# Как работает данный код? с++

Tags: c++

Решаю задачи из CSES Problem Set. Сразу оставлю ссылку на саму задачу, где можно найти условие и проверяющую систему: [ссылка](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/2162/)

Решил сначала задачу простым путем, просто через `set<int>` с удалением элементов, но на последних двух тестах получаю вердикт `TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED`.

Ничего не придумав, решил поискать решение в интернете, и наткнулся на вот такой код:

```
int n; cin>>n;
int a = 1, b = 0;
while(n > 0) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i+=2) {
        cout<<a*i + b<<' ';
    }
    if (n&1) cout<<a + b<<' ', b += a;
    else b -= a;
    a <<= 1;
    n >>= 1;
}
```

И вот вопрос, как работает этот код? Я несколько раз прошелся дебагером, но так ничего и не понял.

Comment: Я так понимаю вас смущают строки: `if (n&1)` - это проверка на четность.  `a <<= 1;` - умножение на два. `n >>= 1;` - деление на два

Comment: @AlexeyVesker хах нет, я не на столько не понял, как работает код. Язык я знаю)  Если у нас `n` нечетное, то мы должны начинать с последнего числа, а если `n` четное, то с первого в ряду. Мне не понятно, что за `b` и `a` и почему `a` умножается на 2? Например деление `n` я тоже вроде понял и это связано с тем, что каждый круг вычеркивания у нас остается в 2 раза меньше элементов. Но вот проблема в понимании `a` и `b`.

Comment: Соответственно `while` выполняется пока есть дети в списке, в `for` выводится номер очередного ребенка в  `if-else` определяется инкремент для вычисления очередного претендента на вылет (в зависимости от того четное кол-во детей или нет). `a` - стартовый номер ребенка, `b`- инкремент

Comment: Пока вы не обежали полный круг, номера образуют арифметическую прогрессию. `a` и `b` - её параметры: шаг и начальное значение. Когда круг пройден, шаг удваивается, начальное значение меняется хитрее. По хорошему надо расписывать метод математической индукции и доказывать что программа делает то что делает.

Comment: Задача Иосифа Флавия - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за ссылку, только я не очень понимаю, как вклинить в этот алгоритм, вывод номера?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это на основе разбора задачи в "Конкретной математике". Но могу и ошибаться...

Comment: @Harry я посмотрел разбор в книге, но опять-таки я не нашел как получить именно порядок удаления элементов. Алгоритм Иосифа Флавия возвращает последнюю оставшуюся позицию, но в задаче требуется вывести порядок удаления. И вроде немного понял, `a` это степень двойки т.к. каждый круг мы убираем половину элементов и этот параметр служит для того, чтобы пропускать и уже вычеркнутые и не вычеркнутые номера, а вот `b` что-то типа поправки, но пока не понимаю как это работает.

Comment: Вобщем, если я не ошибаюсь, выводятся сначала каждое второе число в пределах [1;n], потом каждое четвертое, восьмое и так далее. Пока не очень разобрался, почему именно так ищется начало каждого цикла, как ищется. Но логика - в выведении чисел с удваиваемым шагом.